# PHP - Variable returns NULL when setting in if statement

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, file-get-contents, isset

I'm somewhat of an amateur php programmer and am looking for help with an if statement that is not working as I intend it to.

```
<?php

var_dump($_GET['name']);
var_dump($_GET['id']);
var_dump($search);
var_dump($param);
var_dump($raw);
var_dump($json);

// for debugging
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

// choose between either the name or id parameter
if(isset($_GET['name'])) {
    $search = $_GET['name'];
}
elseif(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $search = $_GET['id'];
}

// build parameters for either name OR id
if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
    $param = http_build_query(array(
        'name' => $_GET['name'],
        'getMembers' => 'yes',
        'rand' => rand(),
    ));
}
elseif (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $param = http_build_query(array(
        'id' => $_GET['id'],
        'getMembers' => 'yes',
        'rand' => rand(),
    ));
}

// get raw json from server
$raw = file_get_contents("https://example.com/file.php?".$param);

// decode the raw json response
$json = json_decode($raw);

... ?>
```

Notice how I've dumped the vars on the third line for debugging purposes.  `$search`, `$param`, `$raw`, and `$json` all return NULL every time.  I'm thinking it has something to do with the if statements, but I can't figure out what for the life of me.  Help would be much appreciated.  Cheers!

EDIT:

Okay!  We're getting somewhere!  I moved `var_dump($json);` farther down the page and got this jumble as a result:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (2) { ["guild"]=> object(stdClass)#1 (11) { ["guild_id"]=> string(3) "182" ["guild_name"]=> string(7) "Jiggmin" ["creation_date"]=> string(19) "2013-05-07 10:32:02" ["active_date"]=> string(19) "2013-05-07 10:32:02" ["member_count"]=> string(1) "1" ["emblem"]=> string(18) "default-emblem.jpg" ["gp_total"]=> string(1) "0" ["gp_today"]=> string(1) "0" ["owner_id"]=> string(7) "1939717" ["note"]=> string(13) "Hehe, trolls." ["active_count"]=> string(1) "0" } ["members"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (6) { ["user_id"]=> string(7) "1939717" ["name"]=> string(11) "snuppaper97" ["power"]=> string(1) "1" ["rank"]=> string(2) "23" ["gp_today"]=> NULL ["gp_total"]=> NULL } } }
```

I then tried to do `echo $json;` on line 58 and got this monstrosity:

`**Recoverable fatal error:** Object of class std class could not be converted to string in /Path/To/File.php on line 58`

Comment: What is the output of GET? var_dump it

Comment: Put `var_dump($search);
var_dump($param);
var_dump($raw);
var_dump($json);` in last line after executing everything and check.

Comment: Where were they defined?

Comment: BTW hands off from globals

Comment: No need for `global` in this case.

Comment: Where do you assign a value to these parameters?

Comment: where are they coming from?

Comment: Your `var_dump()`s at the top of the code are being executed before the various tests set those variables up.  Execution happens from top to bottom - the variables you set at the bottom are not set to anything and don't exist at the top.

Answer (score 0):

They are at the top of the script, so these vars haven't been defined!

```
var_dump($search);
var_dump($param);
var_dump($raw);
var_dump($json);
```

They were always going to be null until you set them as something! Where are the vars supposed to come from? Move the var_dumps below and you'll probably start seeing stuff :-)

EDIT: Now you have an object of stdClass. To json encode that, we must convert it to an array! It's as easy as:

```
$array = (array) $object;
$json = json_encode($array);
```

Comment: Thank you!  Progress is being made!  Please see my edits.

Answer (score 0):

- First of all, do not use globals, they are a very old and bad way of coding in php.
- instead of `isset($_GET['name'])` use `array_key_exists('name', $_GET)` as `isset($_GET['name'])` returns false if it is set to NULL, if you don't want null either explicitly add `null !== $_GET['name']` as well, that way you know exactly what the code is doing.

there seems to be no default for your parameters, eg, if none of them are ever set, there will be no new parameter string build

Can you provide us with a sample url and the code where you build the url ? or where you use `$param`

Comment: So I took the advice of others to move `var_dump($json);` father down the php script and got something php can't handle.  Please see my edits and lmk if you can help.  Thanks!